# boto3 cloudformation Parameter validation failed

Tags: aws-cloudformation, boto3

I have created below parameters which supposed to be passed while calling cloudformation client for create SNS stack command.

```
pubSNSCFParameters = []
        pubSNSCFParameters.append("{'ParameterKey': 'Environment','ParameterValue':'" + Constants.Env + "'}")
        pubSNSCFParameters.append("{'ParameterKey':'pDisplayName','ParameterValue':'" + SNSStackName + "'}")
        pubSNSCFParameters.append("{'ParameterKey':'pTopicName','ParameterValue':'" + SNSStackName + "'}")
```

which gives like below output:

```
["{'ParameterKey': 'Environment', 'ParameterValue': 'dev'}", u"{'ParameterKey': 'pDisplayName', 'ParameterValue': 'some-big-value'}", u"{'ParameterKey': 'pTopicName', 'ParameterValue': 'asome-big-value'}"]
```

now while I run my boto3 client to create the stack for SNS i'm getting 
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:

```
Invalid type for parameter Parameters[0], value: {'ParameterKey': 'Environment', 'ParameterValue': 'dev'}, type: <type 'str'>, valid types: <type 'dict'>
```

code snippet:

```
with open(templatelocation + 'CFT_SNS.json', 'r') as f:

client.create_stack(StackName=stackName,
              TemplateBody=f.read(),
              Parameters=pubSNSCFParameters ,
             Capabilities=['CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM'],
             Tags=[
              {
            'Key': 'CreatorName',
           'Value': 'some@email.com'
            },
            ]
        )
```

i would imagine this as to do with datatypes of parameter, so how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters are string:

```
"{'ParameterKey': 'Environment', 'ParameterValue': 'dev'}" <-- note quotations at the beginning and end.
```

This is because you are appending strings to `pubSNSCFParameters`:

```
pubSNSCFParameters.append("{'ParameterKey': 'Environment','ParameterValue':'" + Constants.Env + "'}")
```

It should be dict:

```
pubSNSCFParameters.append({'ParameterKey': 'Environment','ParameterValue': Constants.Env})
```

Assuming `Constants.Env` is string.

Comment: @change198 No problem. Acceptance of the answer would be thus appreciated.